# chrome-error://chromewebdata/ All of a sudden showed up using Cypress testing Package

Tags: testing, automation, cypress

I was using Cypress to test a Tableau Dashboard with no problems showing up at first. Then one day I started getting this chrome-error. I have all the proxy's set. I'm using the {"chromeWebSecurity": false} fix but to no avail.

*Cypress.json*

```
{
    "chromeWebSecurity": false,
    "baseUrl": "https://to dashboard",
    "defaultCommandTimeout": 30000,
    "requestTimeout": 30000,
    "env" : {
        "username": "username",
        "password": "password"
    }
}
```

I've tried to navigate to google.com and get the same error. I have noticed I can navigate to HTTP sites ok but not HTTPS sites. Another point is when starting my test it has to go to a login page but there is no new tab required it opens on the same page.

*Test*

```
describe('test of hover', function() {
               
  beforeEach(() => {
      cy.visit('#/projects/678')
      cy.get('input#username').type(Cypress.env('username'))
      cy.get('input#password').type(Cypress.env('password'),{log:false})
      cy.get('a#signOnButton').click()
      cy.get('a[href="another page"').click()
      cy.get('a[href= "another page"').click()
      cy.log('starting to find Icons')
      cy.loadPage()
      cy.wait("@dataGetFirst")
      })
```

As i said this was working before and I don't understand why it has changed so suddenly. I'm using Cypress 9.5.3 and running Chrome 100. I am very new to this and would appreciate any help at'll.

Test run:

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. [Please don't post screenshots of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/354577). They can't be searched or copied, or even consumed by users of adaptive technologies like screen readers. Instead, paste the code as text directly into your question. If you select it and click the `{}` button or Ctrl+K the code block will be indented by four spaces, which will cause it to be rendered as code.